# Sql simple beginner operation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named `USERS` with `user_id` as primary key and `user_name`.

I have another table `USERS_ACT` with `user_act_id` primary key, `user_act_user_id` and another 2 columns.

I need `user_act_user_id` to be foreign key in `USERS`? How can I achieve this?

This is my first day in SQL so please be kind to explain if what I ask is wrong.

Comment: mysql and I use dbvisualizer to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume you are not the DB admin and you just want to get all the active users' names ;))

```
select users.user_name
from users
join users_act on users.user_id = users_act.user_act_user_id
```

Comment: this is actually what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Without referencial integrity it's up to you to make it work, there's no "magic" around it.

Populate your user_act_user_id with a pk-value from USERS and there you have it.

You may want to add constraints, but that may not be what you're asking for,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx

In short, they keep the keys between tables in good shape.

Comment: so bassicaly my user_act_user_id will have values that are also in user_id from users so this is my FK ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your DB Type if MySql even supports foreign keys. For example you can use foreign keys with InnoDB format but not with MyIsam format.
When working with MySql i personally prefer working with MyIsam and do most of the checking about integrity while programming. 
In general you can just add user_act_user_id in your table USERS but not mark it as any key. After that you can simple use a JOIN, but ofc the referencial integrity is not given so have to write your own "trigger" on programming site if you want f.e. to automaticly delete data belonging to a user in the other table. Otherwise you have to use constraints or triggers, but this might be not that easy when just started with SQL.

Comment: I was reffering to a "trigger" as a check on programming site not on db site, sry if this was missunderstood.

Comment: @Chriss: OK. Unfortunately I cannot reverse my downvote (unless you edit your answer). Although I still think that referential integrity should always be checked in the database as well.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my question because i found another grammer mistake^^

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using InnoDB (which is the only engine that supports foreign keys):

```
ALTER TABLE users_act
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_act_users
        FOREIGN KEY (user_act_user_id) 
        REFERENCES users (user_id);
```