# MySQL simple beginner query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `users` with `id,name,score`.

I need a query that returns the average score for all persons whose name starts with m.

I'm a beginner to SQL so please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had edited your question to make it look more appealing. Please ensure that hence forth you format your questions so that it does not look like a wall of text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql simple beginner operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580987/sql-simple-beginner-operation)

Comment: @Fofole: Please don't edit your question as severely as you did. At first you've been talking about `score`. Accepted answer also talks about this score. But your question has been edited so many times that answers are completely irrelevant of the question. **Also**: Duplicate that you suggest talks about joins and not the aggregate functions you're after... So. **I suggest you revert your question back to a revision that matches accepted answer**. Or we will.

Comment: @Fofole: Question should be reverted to revision #2, because it's the last revision that talks about user `score` and is also properly formatted.

Comment: FYI: Meta discussion about this question and its drastic edits http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125342/137977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(score) FROM users
WHERE name LIKE 'm%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE) FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE 'M%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(score)
from users
where name like 'm%'
```